# Elasticsearch unexpected results when deleting by filtered query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete a set of documents that do not match a field with a certain value by sending the following data through a DELETE request to "localhost:9200/products/phone":

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": []
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "batch": 1433585920
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this query ends up deleting ALL documents of the /products/phone type, including the documents that have the 1433586041 value in 'batch'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting in the way that you are doing it is deleting the index's type, `phone`:

```
curl -XDELETE host:9200/products/phone -d '{ ... }'
```

The request payload is ignored in this case. [You need to use the `_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html):

```
curl -XDELETE host:9200/products/phone/_query -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "batch": 1433585920
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

All of that said, [Delete By Query is a little bit trappy and I suggest that you do *not* use it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10067). The [goal is to completely rewrite it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7052), but that has not happened yet -- the suggestion is therefore to use the Scan/Scroll API to find documents matching your filter, then delete them using the Bulk API by ID. It's more effort, but it will be a better solution for cluster stability until the Delete By Query endpoint is rewritten.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your query however is not working and is giving me a 'ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: source is missing;]'. Perhaps the mapping is of some use to you http://pastebin.com/kd9gPQqJ

Comment: I read the issues with delete by query and am currently working on a scan/scroll solution, but I'd still love to know whether it's posssible using one query

Comment: @MarcelEmblazoned Ah, woops! I forgot to add the `-d` argument for `curl` and then put it in quotes so that it worked for the multiline version.